# How critical is water during germination? Should I re-sow?

Tags: watering, seedlings, germination

I just started some veggie seeds 5 days ago.  I soaked the soil after planting them, but have totally forgotten to water them since.  When I watered them (just now) the soil wasn't dry, but I wouldn't call it moist either.  The seeds are in a typical 1'x2' tray with a clear greenhouse lid on it and a

Everyone says this time is really important for watering.  If this initial lapse is going to cause any future delay in growth, I'll just go ahead and replant these.

Comment: Any updates on how they're doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seeds need to stay moist but you don't want to drown them. Sounds like you're seeding in a 1020 flat with a humidity dome. The humidity dome will help retain moisture.

I'm assuming you're also using a typical seed starting mix that contains a lot of peat moss. You can tell if the the mix is too dry for seeds to germinate if the color on the top has gone from black to brown. That still may not have a negative effect on germination if you can water it in time.

I cover the inserts in my trays with plastic wrap and they usually don't need additional water until the seeds start to germinate and I have removed the plastic. If the humidity dome you have provides a decent seal it should be similar for you.

What did you plant and what is the room temperature where you have your tray? I usually start to see germination of tomatoes in a couple of days, eggplants and peppers after 7. I have my trays heated though to speed up germination. After 5 days you should have seen some form of life depending on what you planted. Either way I think you should wait 2-4 days before making any decisions. It shouldn't impact your plans at all.If the seeds start to germinate, wait another week and replant just the cells that didn't germinate.

Comment: I went ahead and watered them and the leeks and bunching onions came up within a week.  Its been about a month and the seedlings are going strong.

Comment: @doub1ejack good to hear.